# I want run another perl script from one perl script , but i need to execute it separately

Tags: windows, perl, windows-console

I need perl script to trigger another script which should run in seperate command prompt.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
system("perl exe_klarity.pl");

#!/usr/bin/perl
system("perl exe_klarity.pl");
```

When run this code its running only in the same command prompt, not getting in seperate window, please help

Comment: Don't run the script (or `perl`), run the program that you use as a console/terminal. It should accept a program to run an option or argument. What OS? What windowing environment? What console/terminal program?

Comment: windows 7, command exe console, C:\Strawberry\perl\bin ENV variable

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
system("start perl exe_klarity.pl");
```

`start` executes a command in a new console window.